# Salt pillar data is empty when using for loop

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I am grabbing data via salt and I'm trying to iterate through all the types of pillars.  It runs but doesn't render anything.

```jinja2
{% for type in salt['pillar.get']('pillar') %}

{% if type in [Action', 'Queue', 'Data', 'Number'] %}
{% for something in salt['pillar.get']('pillar:{{ type }}:subtype') %}

 copy_init_script_{{ type }}_{{ something }}:
   file.managed:
 - name: /blah/blah/somefile-{{ ptype }}-{{ something }}
 - source: salt:/folder/anothertemplate.jinja
 - template: jinja
 - context:
    something: {{ something }}
    atype: {{ type }}
 - timeout: 10
 {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Why doesn't the for loop seem to be getting any data?

Comment: Is there a "pillar" key in your pillar data? It doesn't by default.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use a Jinja variable expression inside a method call.  Instead, just use the variable directly with string concatenation, like normal Python.

```
{% for something in salt['pillar.get']('pillar:' + type + ':subtype') %}
```

Notice that it's `+ type +` rather than `{{ type }}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `salt['pillar.get']` function requires a key. By default, there is no `pillar` key. Just the keys of the key/value pairs in your pillar dictionary.

If you just want to iterate over all the key/value pairs in your pillar data, just iterate directly over the pillar dictionary

Something like this:

```
{% for type in pillar %}

{% if type in [Action', 'Queue', 'Data', 'Number'] %}
{% for something in salt['pillar.get']('pillar:{{ type }}:subtype') %}

 copy_init_script_{{ type }}_{{ something }}:
   file.managed:
 - name: /blah/blah/somefile-{{ ptype }}-{{ something }}
 - source: salt:/folder/anothertemplate.jinja
 - template: jinja
 - context:
    something: {{ something }}
    atype: {{ type }}
 - timeout: 10
 {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should be something close to that.